# Should I stay in a Job that pays well but is not a challenge?

Tags: job-satisfaction

I'm in a position that I think many people would like to be in. I have a job that pays well, demands little and offers a lot of flexibility in terms of how you approach the work.

So long as I get my work done in a satisfactory manor, I'm able to schedule my hours to my liking each week. I can come and go as I please. Work from the office or stay home. Health insurance is also good. I've gained enough experience to where the work is easy to finish.

All in all it's provided a good living and with the retirement plan and built in raises I can ride it all the way into the sunset and provide a comfortable life for me and my family.

However, the job is no longer a challenge and I finish the day feeling unsatisfied in my work.
I have an education background in computer science, and I'd like to branch out into that field of work.

The question is, if I'm already fairly secure financially with a job that a lot of people would love to have, would I be a fool if I left it for something else?

I've talked to some co-workers about it, and they think I'd be foolish to leave. They say if you're looking for more challenging work, pick up a new hobby in your free time instead of getting a whole new job.

Comment: This is really really your choice. Make one.

Comment: What is your primary reason for having a job?

Comment: Have you considered asking your employer to add more demands or responsibilities?

Comment: I would suggest re-writing the question - ultimately we cannot decide for you or answer the question as to what is more important to you: Job Satisfaction or a Salary that maintains your current lifestyle. What we can help answer are things like how to branch out into another industry, how to setup a side-venture, how to pivot within a company etc.

Answer (score 3):

The only advice I could give is that:
If you have a family and people you care for e.g. children, elderly or disabled, I would be very cautious and advise against it. Maybe if children are older if you have any?
Otherwise, if you are quite independent in this regard, then it's up to you. Preferably you could improve your skills, build a portfolio, contribute to open source projects. Then apply for positions, but be fussy, don't settle for something much worse, Preferably the same level of financial security and flexibility.

Also how much you are confident that your current skills are relevant in the job market and how secure the job is really? Maybe trying to get more challenging job will be good insulation against less certain times. But it's hard to know without knowledge of position or your employer's industry.